# CodeIgniter application links not working

Tags: codeigniter

I installed an application built with CodeIgniter on my local computer which has MAMP.  The home page contains a bunch of links to other pages.  Clicking any of the links doesn't do anything.  The page just refreshes but the browser doesn't redirect.  Looking at this piece of ducumentation, I think that the URI doesn't have any data and therefore it just goes back to the home page.  What do I need to do to test this and fix it?

There are three reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.

Comment: it does use session or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means or how to check.

Comment: it needs to login?

Comment: no.  The home page has a bunch of links that need to redirect to other modules within the application.  But when I click it, the URL changes but the page remains the same.  I think it has to do with the URI not loading data.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `base_url` of your application in `config.php` to the same url you are using to access the website, it should be something like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/your_app_directory_name";
```

It should work.

For `.htaccess` use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: the problem still remains

Comment: <IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

Comment: I did this but there are still no changes.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: @MG1 .. that's all you can do in codeigniter's configurations. your problem gotta be in server's (mamp) configurations .. maybe `mod_rerwrite` is not enabled!

Answer (score 1):

change your **.htaccess** to Codeingiter's provide htaccess file below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

place that to your root application folder.

Comment: the htaccess file is there with all this code but still nothing happens when I click on a link.  Any other ideas?

Comment: where do I find this?  I am seeing that the way this application was built was that all the controllers are in a folder called modules.

Comment: defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends MX_Controller { public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('url');
        }
        public function index()
 { $this->load->view('_partials/_header');
          $this->load->view('home');
          $this->load->view('_partials/_footer'); }}

Comment: we better solve this if we can send message to each other.

Comment: you need to create a controller inside core folder that extends your main controller to CI_Controller.

Comment: how do I message you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197190/discussion-between-curiosity-and-mg1).